# "Received unknown parameter: 0" Stripe Api error

Tags: php, stripe-payments, backend

I´m implementing a subscription method for a web app, right now creating everything but the subscription itself has worked. Buen when trying to create a subscription with stripe docs it throws a "Received unknown parameter: 0" and I don´t know why.

```
//
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('KEY');    

$stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'cus_HWAaGjkeQMmJdj',
        'items' => [['price' => 'price_1GxAadBKTcCfnJHQwxEIcqNt']],
    ]);
```

I´m using a customer and a price that I know that exists, but ir throws the same error. And the example is the same as my code. Anyone has an idea about why this error happens?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the service oriented model [1], the correct syntax is:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'customer' => 'cus_xxx',
  'items' => [
    ['price' => 'price_xxx'],
  ],
]);
```

Hope that helps!

[1] https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/wiki/Migration-to-StripeClient-and-services-in-7.33.0

Answer (score 0):

The field `customer` is required when creating a Stripe subscription.

So:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'cus_HWAaGjkeQMmJdj',
        'items' => [['price' => 'price_1GxAadBKTcCfnJHQwxEIcqNt']],
        'customer' => CUSTOMER_ID
    ]);
```

You can see more on their API documentation page. [Press here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create)

Comment: Thanks, I tried both codes, but it looks like here we were sending the customer_id Twice, one alone athe the beggining and un "customer" => CUSTOMER_ID, both are the Customer ID.